# Atomic man story identification

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am trying to identify a story where a man drinks a potion of dark matter that makes him increasing smaller so that he slips through atoms and sees universes in them. Story/stories probably between 50's to 70's, probably magazines. I'm reading a non-English adaptation and want to identify source.

Comment: How certain are you that it was drinking a potion of black matter? Because I can give you two stories off the bat that involve different methods of shrinking and then seeing further universes between atoms.

Comment: And given you're reading the adaptation now, can you provide further details? I provided three possible stories below.

Answer (score 4):

On the off chance that you're mistaking the method used to start shrinking, [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117756/what-is-this-shrinking-scientist-story/117757) holds two separate answers involving a person shrinking until they start seeing universe between atoms. "[He Who Shrank](http://johnnypez9.blogspot.com/2010/06/he-who-shrank-by-henry-hasse-part-1.html)" is a 1936 story by Henry Hasse about a scientist's assistant who gets injected by his scientist metaphor with his "Shrinx" formula and he becomes so small that he is huge in another universe and then continues shrinking until he winds up at Earth.

"[Submicroscopic](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?44012)" involves a shrinking machine with the scientist finding a beautiful princess in one of the worls within atoms. The *[Girl in the Golden Atom](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/446473.The_Girl_in_the_Golden_Atom)* involves "a young chemist who finds a hidden atomic world within his mother’s wedding ring". :) It's a fairly common trope in science fiction.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot! The author who adapted possibly added the dark matter potion angle to the common trope.

Comment: The series I'm reading is in Bengali (prof. nat boltu chakra 1963-2008) and it's author has rampantly borrowed and adapted plot points and novums from mainly golden-age American SF. This one for instance follows the first few sections from "He Who Shrank" and then returns the traveler to his original circumstances.

Comment: He does observe his own Earth around chapter 5 or so. "I tried to do as he said, again I felt the cold probing tendrils in my brain, and a lethargy came over my mind. Shadows flashed across the screen, then suddenly a familiar scene leaped into view: the Professor's laboratory as I had last seen it, on the night of my departure. No sooner had this scene cleared than I entered the room, exactly as I had on that night. I saw myself approach the table close behind the Professor, saw him standing as he had stood, staring out at the night sky; saw his lips move."

Comment: @annem: So, if I'm understanding correctly, Adrish Bardhan adapted an existing story and you're trying to find what source he based it off of? Or is this a translation of a story that you're trying to locate?

Comment: Yep, he's borrowing large chunks (the whole series is like that) from existing stories and I'm trying to pin down sources (dissertation writing); Bardhan also adds and subtracts many plot points and Indianizes locations and relationships. For instance, the traveler in the Bengali story does not observe his own earth or get there by getting progressively smaller. He just gets called back by the power of the dark matter/fohat concoction. Now I'm not sure if the "source" stories were credited in the first publication since I only have the collected volumes..so it's really interesting!