# Golden age science fiction comic about shrinking man

Tags: story-identification, comics

I’m trying to find a comic from the golden age era about a scientist that is sitting in a psychiatrist office describing an experiment that went awry and has him continuously shrinking, finding out that each atom is another solar system. The doctor thinks the man is crazy until he looks up from his notes just in time to see the man shrink from view. Please help me!

Comment: It might have been Lost In the Microcosm, Buzz. I read the story in a hardback anthology book some years ago. If it helps there was also a story about some space explorers whose ship ends up in sauerkraut battling microorganisms.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you're thinking of "Lost in the Microcosm", a story in EC Comics's *Weird Science* #12 (dated May-June 1950), which was an adaptation of Henry Hasse's "[He Who Shrank](http://johnnypez9.blogspot.com/2010/06/he-who-shrank-by-henry-hasse-part-1.html)" ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/He_Who_Shrank)).

> A world-celebrated professor reveals to his assistant, the tale's narrator, that he has discovered that the visible universe at the largest scales corresponds to the microscopic universe at the smallest observed scales, the relations between universe's planets suns, and star cluster being identical to the relations of electrons, atomic nuclei, molecules. Rather than explore the universe at their own scale, the professor intends to explore the worlds endlessly nested within matter itself, which he argues by induction, must go on to ever smaller levels, and claims to have invented a substance, that once-applied will cause an individual to perpetually shrink. His assistant thinks him insane, but the professor, surprising the assistant, injects him with the substance, temporarily paralyzing the assistant and dooming him to eternally shrink ever smaller, through successively smaller worlds, each a subatomic particle of the previous one. (The injected substance, "Shrinx", has engineered secondary properties such as oxygenating the blood and protecting against heat loss in space.) The professor will monitor the assistant's fate through a device that receives his sense of sight and sound, and intends to eventually follow suit and set himself shrinking as well, although they would never meet again due to the infinitesimal chance of tracing the same path through the subatomic worlds.

Here's a motion comic version of it (he begins to shrink into the chair around the 16 minute mark):

NOTE: *Weird Science* #12 was actually the first issue of *Weird Science*; it took over the numbering of another comic. This has to do with postal regulations at the time; and, due to issues with those regulations, they changed the numbering to #5 as of the fifth issue (so, #12 - 15, then #5 - 22). So, this is the *first* *Weird Science* #12.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: The short story has been provided as an answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117756/what-is-this-shrinking-scientist-story/117757#117757 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146784/atomic-man-story-identification/146788#146788 albeit neither accepted.

Comment: Note that neither of the answer links @FuzzyBoots lists in his comment refers to the comic book - as he says in the comment, both refer to the original prose short story.